# Prevent calls to error_reporting() and/or ini_set('display_errors', 'On') from overriding php.ini settings

Tags: php, error-reporting

I had this setting in my php.ini file:

```
error_reporting = E_ERROR|E_PARSE|E_CORE_ERROR|E_COMPILE_ERROR
```

But I was still receiving thousands of NOTICE and WARNING entries in the error log every minute. I of course realize I would better deal with those errors, but this is not my code and I am not being paid to do that, I just needed to get rid of those fat error_log files (Gbs per day).

I searched through the code and removed all `error_reporting()` calls, and that did the trick but, is there a way to disallow `error_reporting()` from overriding php.ini settings?

Could I also prevent calls to `ini_set('display_errors')` from overriding php.ini settings?

Comment: As I said, that is what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to disallow error_reporting() from overriding php.ini settings?

Maybe.

If you're using mod_php under Apache (or FastCGI via FPM), you can use [`php_admin_value` and `php_admin_flag`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) to *force* certain INI settings in such a way that `ini_set` will be unable to override.

Unfortunately I don't know of a way to neuter `error_reporting` other than [`disable_functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) -- but this will throw a PHP Warning every time it's used.

(As a side note, I find it curious that a developer would set an error reporting level *in production* and still be producing such a high volume of logs.)

Comment: Yes, I am using mod_php, I didn't know about that, I will give it a go.

Comment: The errors are mainly caused by external libraries added to the the main code for things like XML and RSS creation, so they produce errors for every entry in the catalog (shop), hence the number. Judging by the entries, most are undefined vars, probably due to code that was intended to run in a different environment.

Comment: Keep in mind that using `disable_functions` makes the function undefined, and calls to undefined functions are fatal errors in newer versions of PHP (Given that this answer is from 2011)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [`disable_functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) php.ini setting and turn off `error_reporting()` and `ini_set()`. But that COMPLETELY disables them, so if you need to change settings other than error_reporting at runtime, you'd be SOL.

Answer (score 0):

According to the following pages, the PHP engine sets when and where a configuration option can be set. There is no way to prevent it programmatically:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php
http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php